# Unexpected copy in unpacking via structured bindings a returned tuple

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

I'm trying to use [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) to return an `std::tuple<std::string, std::vector<std::string_view>>`, which represents a string and string-views pointing to the said string.

Attempting to do this as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

using Views = std::vector<std::string_view>;

std::tuple<std::string, Views> create(std::string sample) {
  std::string surface = sample;
  Views views;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sample.size(); i++) {
    std::string_view view(surface.data() + i, 1);
    views.push_back(view);
  }
  return std::make_tuple(std::move(surface), std::move(views));
}

template <class T> void emit(const T &surface) {
  std::cout << "[" << reinterpret_cast<const void *>(surface.data()) << "..."
            << reinterpret_cast<const void *>(surface.data() + surface.size())
            << "]";
}

int main() {
  std::string line;
  while (getline(std::cin, line)) {
    auto [surface, views] = create(line);
    std::cout << "Surface: ";
    emit(surface);
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "Views: ";
    for (auto view : views) {
      emit(view);
      std::cout << " ";
    }
  }
  std::cout << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

This gets me the following output:

```
$ ./a.out <<< "12"
Surface: [0x7ffdc689aa68...0x7ffdc689aa6a]
Views: [0x7ffdc689a980...0x7ffdc689a981] [0x7ffdc689a981...0x7ffdc689a982]
```

Upon close inspection, it is evident that the string address and the addresses pointed to by the views are different, i.e the views point to an older string, and the string appears to have been copied while the older one destroyed.

I figure I must be doing something wrong here. Why is this wrong? What is the correct way to achieve the intent using structured bindings?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem lies in `create`.

Specifically, you create a view over a string:

```
std::string_view view(surface.data() + i, 1);
```

But that string is a local variable in your function:

```
std::string surface = sample;
```

That string is moved from in the return statement, leaving that local string empty, and then that local string dies, leading to UB. This is because the string might contain the buffer on the stack due to SBO.

```
std::tuple<std::string, Views> create(std::string sample) {
  std::string surface = sample; // local string
  Views views;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sample.size(); i++) {
    std::string_view view(surface.data() + i, 1); // view over the local string
    views.push_back(view);
  }

  // moves surface, leaving surface empty.
  // The string views have a size but may point to an empty string because SBO.
  // It is already UB reading from such string views if SBO is used
  return std::make_tuple(std::move(surface), std::move(views));
} // surface destroyed, all pointer to that string are invalidated.
```

The move constructor of string can require to copy the string data into another buffer in the case of SBO, so you cannot assume a string view is still valid after moving the string.

Comment: the views point to the buffer on the heap, the buffer ownership was moved into the returned tuple, your answer has nothing to do with the question, the question is why is the tuple in the `return tuple` and the tuple in `main` using different buffers, when it was moved into it.

Comment: What is a clean way to keep the return signature intact and move the original-string and the views to the call-site? Is this possible? I'm currently working around this by passing an output parameter (`surface`) as a reference to point to it. I'm looking for an option that uses structured bindings and is contained, if it exists.

Comment: Since strings use SBO, you'll have to move that string to the heap, or allocate a buffer to copy the string into

Comment: @AhmedAEK This is not true. The views point to the stack depending on the size of the string, and std::string don't guarantee address stability when moving anyway.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot i think you should outline SBO better in your answer.

Comment: @AhmedAEK but I do? I can maybe write more about it.

Answer (score 2):

the culprit here is short string optimization.

when the input is very small, the string buffer is allocated on the stack, not on the heap, so your views are pointing to a buffer on the stack ... this has to be copied and cannot be moved.

if the input string was much taller, then the buffer would be allocated on the heap, and all `surface` versions will be pointing to the same location.

a solution here is to use a `vector<char>` which is guaranteed to be stored on the heap, and you can still get a `string_view` into it.

```cpp
std::tuple<std::vector<char>, Views> create(const std::string& sample) {
  std::vector<char> surface(sample.begin(),sample.end());
  // no other code changes
}
```

Comment: This is helpful since you actually solve's OP's problem, while I simply explained the reason why the code was wrong.